# Tiled screen-shots on the OSX version

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm currently running Borderlands 2 natively (Steam Version) on my Mac and I would like to know if anyone has found out where the screen-shots taken with the console command `tiledshot 6` are saved or if that option is disabled in the Mac Version.

If anyone is unfamiliar with Tiledshot I suggest you look at this, it's amazing!
[Tiled Screenshots - Gearbox Forum](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=152140)

Comment: Tiledshot says it's cross platform: http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/TakingScreenshots.html however I'm totally unfamiliar with using it

Comment: Yes, I think the command really works in the game but it seems to me that the programm doesn't know where to save the file it has just created...

Comment: Tiled screenshots look awesome but if you can't figure it out you can use CMD+Shift+3 to take an full screen shot through OS X

Answer (score 1):

It's found in `~/Library/Application Support/Steam/userdata/[number]` and then from there mine was in `/760/remote/49520/screenshots/`

Some of those numbers seem automatically generated however, so it's possible yours will be in a different spot. I used [fseventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start) to find my screenshots. The way I did it was:

- Open up BL2 and get the `tiledshot x y` command ready
- Open fseventer, hit play
- Switch back to BL2 and run the command
- Switch back to fseventer and you should the location of the new screenshot somewhere in the diagram of files

I'm sure there's a better way, but that should work.